# C# add item to JSON object

Tags: c#, json

I have this object and I want to add an other day to it.

```
[{
    "stone":"5kg",
    "years":
    [{
        "year":"2017",
        "stone":"5kg",
        "months":
        [{
            "month":"august",
            "stone":"0.5kg",
            "days":
            [{
                "day":"14",
                "stone":"0.1kg"
            }]
        }],
        "weeks":
        [{
            "week":"01",
            "stone":"0.5kg"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I have this stored in a file and I deserialize it like so:

```
string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\luuk\desktop\test1.json");
var _data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(file);
```

Now I want to add a day to it but I just can't figure it out.
I tried something like this:

```
_data.Add(new Data()
{

});

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\luuk\desktop\test1.json", json);
```

but I can only access years[] and stone in there.

These are my classes:

```
public class Data
{
    public string stone { get; set; }
    public List<Years> years { get; set; }
}

public class Years
{
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string stone { get; set; }
    public List<Months> months { get; set; }
    public List<Weeks> weeks { get; set; }
}

public class Months
{
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string stone { get; set; }
    public List<Days> days { get; set; }
}

public class Days
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public string stone { get; set; }
}

public class Weeks
{
    public string week { get; set; }
    public string stone { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I add an other day to the object?

(I have translated all the variabels in my code from dutch to english so there my be some that I forgot or some typo's)

Comment: You need to add a day to every month in every year or to some specific month in specific year?

Comment: to a specific month in specific year. (2017 - august)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the year and month first where you want to add another day. Here is how you can do that:

```
// Update the data in one line 
_data[0].years.First(x=> x.year == "2017") // Get the year "2017"
        .months.First(x=> x.month == "august") // Get the month "august"
        .days.Add(new Days { day = "15", stone = "0.5kg" }); // Add a new day
```

> OR

```
// Get the year 
Years year = _data.years.First(x=> x.year == "2017");

// Get the month
Months month = year.months.First(x=> x.month == "august");

// Add the day in the month
month.days.Add(new Days { day = "15", stone = "0.5kg" });
```

Comment: I get a compiler error with your first code block: `'List<Data>' does not contain a definition for 'years'`

Comment: Okay, thank you. this worked. I only had to use `_data[0]` instead of `_data` and I have changed all my arrays to lists.

Comment: LuukWuijster glad it worked! I have also updated the code after @mason pointed out that error.

Answer (score 1):

You're using arrays. You can't add things to already initialized arrays, they're fixed-size.

Change all arrays of `T[]` to `List<T>` and then you can call `.Add()` on them to add items.